# how do i get headers on a website with python

Tags: python, botnet

**to give you some context i am building a botnet and i need to get the authorization header from
here is  the link** https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me

**I have already tried this**

> `user = requests.get( "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me", headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": token},  ).json()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following way.

```
response = requests.get("https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me")
response.headers
```

You can find further details at the following [link](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-get-set-http-headers-cookies-and-manage-sessions-use-python-requests-module/#:%7E:text=Python%20requests%20module%E2%80%99s%20headers%20property%20is%20used%20to,HTTP%20response%20headers%20in%20a%20JSON%20format%20string.).